# javax.mail.SendFailedException: Invalid Addresses (While trying to send emal using Rediffmail)

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

This program attempts to send email by first connecting to `smtp.rediffmail.com` . There is no compile time error or compile time exception.But as i try to run the following program it generates the following exception.

**javax.mail.SendFailedException: Invalid Addresses;
  nested exception is:
        com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPAddressFailedException: 421 Authorization failed: please authenticate by
 doing get message first**

I can't figure out what the exception is and why i am getting this exception .

Here is the complete program.In this i have tried to make *TLS* connection with rediffmail server.

```
import javax.mail.Authenticator;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import java.util.Properties;

class rediff {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
      Properties props = new Properties();
      props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.rediffmail.com");
      props.put("mail.stmp.user", "from");

      //To use TLS
      props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
      props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
      props.put("mail.smtp.password", "password");

      Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, new Authenticator() {
        @Override
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
               String username = "from";
               String password = "password";
                return new PasswordAuthentication("from", "password");
            }
      });
       String to = "me@gmail.com";
       String from = "from@rediff.com";
       String subject = "Testing...";
       MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
         try {
           msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
           msg.setRecipient(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
           msg.setSubject(subject);
           msg.setText("rediff program working...!");
           Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
           transport.send(msg);
           System.out.println("fine!!");
         }   catch(Exception exc) {
                 System.out.println(exc);
              }
   }
}
```

Why do i get this exception ?

Answer (score 1):

as per: http://www.techtalkz.com/microsoft-outlook/193842-pop3.html

> In your account settings, enable the "Log on to incoming server before
>   sending mail" on the "Outgoing Server" tab of your account properties. How
>   to locate these properties and tabs is Outlook version-specific but you
>   decided that information wasn't important.

The error is specific to the SMTP service you are trying to use from your client.  It's not a code problem.  Check your `rediffmail.com` account settings

Comment: I don't find any option of this sort there

Comment: @grassPro ... any reason why you're running around putting -1 and not providing feedback or comments?  seems a little silly.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the code is this:

```
Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
transport.send(msg);
```

the send method is a static method and you are not suppose to access it with an instance of Transport class. it should be - Transport.send(msg);

Answer (score -1):

You're trying to use TLS auth but I don't see any port settings in your code. Usually smtp server uses different ports for TLS/SSL authentication, try setting it via `mail.smtp.socketFactory.port`. For TLS default value is `587`, for SSL - `993` as far as I remember.

```
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", port);
    props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
```

Comment: Are port settings really necessary with TLS ?? By the way same exception

Comment: This is with SSL . I am trying with TLS . Please read the question